# Not able to store the data into hbase using pig when I dont know the number of columns in a file

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig

I have a text file with N number of columns (Not sure, in the future I may have N+1).

Example:

```
1|A

2|B|C

3|D|E|F
```

I want to store above data into hbase using pig without writing UDF. How can I store this kind of data without knowing the number of columns in a file?

Answer (score 0):

Put it in a map and then you can use cf1:* where cf1 is your column family